# "Successor" for rational numbers (generate all rationals recursively starting from a specific one)

Tags: rational-numbers, peano-axioms

Is it possible to generate the rational numbers similar to the successor function for natural numbers in this way:

$\bullet$ We know that the rationals can all be put in a sequence $a_0,a_2,...$ since there's a bijection from $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$ (let's consider $\mathbb{N}$ to also include $0$).

$\bullet$ We want to find a function $f:\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a_0 = s$ and $a_k = \underbrace{f(f(...f(s)..))}_{k \ \text{times}}, k\geq 1$, where $s$ can be some rational number (doesn't matter which one, it could be, for example, $0$ as in the case of the natural numbers).

Comment: Simply define $f(a_k)=a_{k+1}$, for all $k\ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what function is $f$?

Comment: @PhantomR That *is* the definition of a function - it's not a particularly *nice* function, of course, but it is a function. (Note that it depends on the enumeration provided, of course - if you define for me an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$, I can turn that into a definition of a function of the type you're looking for.)

Comment: Its definition is right there. It's exactly as explicit as the enumeration of the rationals *you* supplied.

Comment: Oh... sorry, I didn't understand exactly what your wrote at first. Thank you very much to you both for your answers and explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, and you've basically already done it. But it will not have some simple self-contained formula or expression, but rather a lengthy description, much like the one you already have there.

The shortest description I can think of is "Let $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots\}$ be an enumeration of the rationals. Define $f:\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Q$ by $f(a_i)=a_{i+1}$ for all $i\in \Bbb N$." If you want an explicit description so you can actually find function values, you will need an explicit description of the enumeration.

Comment: To be fair, that's not *quite* a complete description - you need to define your enumeration for this to really be an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you!!! :) I've also found this: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1046461